# Change selected rows into columns

Tags: regex, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, pivot

I have a dataframe with the below structure

```
+------+-------------+--------+
|region|          key|     val|
+--------------------+--------+
|Sample|row1         |       6|
|Sample|row1_category|   Cat 1|
|Sample|row1_Unit    |      Kg|
|Sample|row2         |       4|
|Sample|row2_category|   Cat 2|
|Sample|row2_Unit    |     ltr|
+------+-------------+--------+
```

I tried to add a column and push the values to from rows to columns, but the category and unit column

I want to convert it into the below structure

```
+------+-------------+--------+--------+--------+
|region|          key|     val|Category|   Unit |
+--------------------+--------+--------+--------+
|Sample|row1         |       6|   Cat 1|      Kg|
|Sample|row2         |       4|   Cat 2|     ltr|
+------+-------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

This i need to do for multiple keys , i ll have row2,row 3 etc

Comment: can you provide more rows and also can perform how you rectify that this value is Unit or Category . As per above i think there is a suffix _category and _unit in your data. can you confirm the same

Comment: yes. You are right. we need to filter using suffix_cat and suffix_unit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve it by grouping by your key and maybe region and aggregate with `collect_list`, using ragex `^[^_]+` you will get all characters until `_` character.

**UPDATE**: You can use `(\\d{1,})` regex to find all numbers from string(capturing groups), for example if you have `row_123_456_unit` and your function looks like `regexp_extract('val,"(\\d{1,})",0)` you will get `123`, if you change last parameter to 1, then you will get `456`. Hope it helps. [test regex](https://regex101.com/r/9ilrYF/9)

```
  df.printSchema()
  df.show()

  val regex1 = "^[^_]+"  // until '_' character
  val regex2 = "(\\d{1,})"  // capture group of numbers

  df.groupBy('region, regexp_extract('key, regex1, 0))
    .agg('region, collect_list('key).as("key"), collect_list('val).as("val"))
    .select('region,
    'key.getItem(0).as("key"),
    'val.getItem(0).as("val"),
    'val.getItem(1).as("Category"),
    'val.getItem(2).as("Unit")
  ).show()
```

output:

```
root
 |-- region: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- val: string (nullable = true)

+------+-------------+-----+
|region|          key|  val|
+------+-------------+-----+
|Sample|         row1|    6|
|Sample|row1_category|Cat 1|
|Sample|    row1_Unit|   Kg|
|Sample|         row2|    4|
|Sample|row2_category|Cat 2|
|Sample|    row2_Unit|  ltr|
+------+-------------+-----+

+------+----+---+--------+----+
|region| key|val|Category|Unit|
+------+----+---+--------+----+
|Sample|row1|  6|   Cat 1|  Kg|
|Sample|row2|  4|   Cat 2| ltr|
+------+----+---+--------+----+
```

Comment: Hi I want to filter based on category present in the key column, not based on _ because sometimes the key column might have row_1_cat and so on. So the regexp should be  something like "^[^_cat]+" or "^[^_uom]+"

Comment: is my regex correct.? I am not good with regex. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi ANdrzejs. Thanks for the solution but i want to use a regular expression which helps me to filter out rows without cat and uom. The one which you have given is fine only if the row name is only row1 and not row_1

Comment: if you want to filter out these rows simply just use this:
`df.filter('key.contains("_cat") || 'key.contains("_unit")).show()`

Comment: The first regular expression doesnt satisfy my requirement as sometimes the key can be row_1 or , row_1_2. The regex you have given works only if the key  is row1

Comment: I think there is an issue with the regex. The idea of the regex is to filter out the columns with _cat and _uom in your group by clause. But the regex which was already there filtered only if it has xxx_cat or xxx_uom. what if we had xxx_yyy_cat or xxx_yyy_uom.

Comment: No, regex in groupBy clause is to standarize "key" values, for example, for values `row1,row1_category,row1_Unit` regex1 will transform them to `row1,row1,row1` and regex2 to `1,1,1`. Then groupBy will group by these values and merge  each group to one row in .agg step

Comment: The problem is the key column may have different values. For eg row_one,row_one_cat,row_cat_uom and so on. the regular expression should remove _cat and _uom from any row it sees it. But the regular expression you have given doesn.t

Comment: good :),  if you need to remove _cat and _uom you can try this `val df = Seq("123_2_cat","123_2","123_2_uom").toDF("val")
  df.select(regexp_replace(regexp_replace('val,"_cat",""),"_uom","")).show()`

Comment: I did the same :) i used regex replace . I mis understood the purpose the first time. I thought you wanted to remove them altogether. I realized later that you just wanted to group them . :) Thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> df.show
+------+-------------+----+
|region|          key| val|
+------+-------------+----+
|Sample|         row1|   6|
|Sample|row1_category|Cat1|
|Sample|    row1_Unit|  Kg|
|Sample|         row2|   4|
|Sample|row2_category|Cat2|
|Sample|    row2_Unit| ltr|
+------+-------------+----+


scala> val df1 = df.withColumn("_temp", split( $"key" , "_")).select(col("region"), $"_temp".getItem(0) as "key",$"_temp".getItem(1) as "colType",col("val"))


scala> df1.show(false)
+------+----+--------+----+
|region|key |colType |val |
+------+----+--------+----+
|Sample|row1|null    |6   |
|Sample|row1|category|Cat1|
|Sample|row1|Unit    |Kg  |
|Sample|row2|null    |4   |
|Sample|row2|category|Cat2|
|Sample|row2|Unit    |ltr |
+------+----+--------+----+


scala> val df2 = df1.withColumn("Category", when(col("colType") === "category", col("val"))).withColumn("Unit", when(col("colType") === "Unit", col("val"))).withColumn("val", when(col("colType").isNull, col("val")))


scala> df2.show(false)
+------+----+--------+----+--------+----+
|region|key |colType |val |Category|Unit|
+------+----+--------+----+--------+----+
|Sample|row1|null    |6   |null    |null|
|Sample|row1|category|null|Cat1    |null|
|Sample|row1|Unit    |null|null    |Kg  |
|Sample|row2|null    |4   |null    |null|
|Sample|row2|category|null|Cat2    |null|
|Sample|row2|Unit    |null|null    |ltr |
+------+----+--------+----+--------+----+


scala> val df3 = df2.groupBy("region", "key").agg(concat_ws("",collect_set(when($"val".isNotNull, $"val"))).as("val"),concat_ws("",collect_set(when($"Category".isNotNull, $"Category"))).as("Category"), concat_ws("",collect_set(when($"Unit".isNotNull, $"Unit"))).as("Unit"))


scala> df3.show()
+------+----+---+--------+----+
|region| key|val|Category|Unit|
+------+----+---+--------+----+
|Sample|row1|  6|    Cat1|  Kg|
|Sample|row2|  4|    Cat2| ltr|
+------+----+---+--------+----+
```

Comment: Hi Nikk. Thanks for your solution. Though the thing is i think i missed a point here.  key will sometimes have row_T_1_cat,row_T_cat. I always want to get the category and UOM based on the CAT and UOM at the end of the string in the key.

Comment: can you give all possible value of Key . For you solution you can using String operator to replace last '_' to any specific delimiter which will not come in your key and further that can be use at place of  " _ " in df1 declaration above.

Comment: every key combination will have a cat and uom. The keys can have multiple _'s and at the end have _cat or _uom